# Leading behavior in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning linear differential equations for my first time and I haven't taken a math class in 3 years so I am a little rusty on some basic concepts as well. I am solving for the leading behavior as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ of $$x^4 y''''= y   \qquad \qquad (1) $$ Here is what I did:
$$
y = x^{\alpha}
$$
$$
y'''' = (\alpha-3)(\alpha-2)(\alpha-1)\alpha x^{\alpha-4}
$$
I plugged it back into (1) and found that I have two quadratics when I let $$ y = (\alpha^2 - 3\alpha) $$
I get $$ y+2y-1 = 0$$
I solve for this and get $$ y_{1,2} = -1 \pm \sqrt{2}$$
So the above expression $$ = (\alpha^2 - 3\alpha)$$
Set these two expressions equal to eachother, then set it equal to zero and I end up with another quadratic
$$ \alpha_{1,2,3,4} = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5\pm4\sqrt{2}}}{6}
$$
I thought I would plug this $\alpha$ back into my expression for y'''' and y then plug those into (1) but since I have 4 different $\alpha $ terms I don't think this is correct. Where should I go from here? If you have a resource you can send me the link or suggest I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I did not do any computation but my first thought was: why would a solution have the form $y(x) = x^{\alpha}$?

Comment: I read this and example 2 seems similar, but once I get the general solution how do I find the leading behavior? https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/eulerequations.aspx

Comment: I am also confused because this link shows the example for 2 roots but I end up with 4 $\alpha$ terms, so I'm not even sure what my solution would look like...